# Kodein vs Dagger - Can't Get Dagger Working w/ Multiple Modules

Tags: java, dagger-2, kodein

([x-post from /r/androiddev](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/cadf00/kodein_vs_dagger_cant_get_dagger_working_w/))

I would just like to preface this by saying that this is not a "which is better" post; this is strictly a question about how I can build something using Dagger (and how I built it in Kodein to help illustrate the problem).

I've been using Kodein for a few years now in several work projects, and I've found it to be so easy to work with, that I never look at Dagger anymore. I started a new personal project, and I thought I'd give Dagger another shot.

To keep things simple, I have 3 modules (this is a regular desktop app not an Android one);

1. app
2. common
3. google

`app` contains a single class `App`:

```
class App(
  private val api: GoogleApi,
  private val argParser: ArgParser
) {
  fun run() {
    while(true) {
      api.login(argParser.username, argParser.password);
    }
  }

}
```

`common` contains a single class `ArgParser` (implementation isn't important)

`google` contains several classes:

```
class GoogleApi(  
  driveProvider: () -> Drive
) {

  private val drive by lazy {
    driveProvider()
  }

  fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    drive.login() // not real call
  }
}

internal class CredentialRetriever(
  private val transport: NetHttpTransport,
  private val jsonFactory: JacksonFactory
) {

  fun retrieveCredentials() = ...

}
```

The dependencies for `google` are:

```
dependencies {

  implementation "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:$googleApiVersion"

  implementation "com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:$googleApiVersion"

  implementation "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-$googleApiVersion"

}
```

I specifically use `implementation` because I don't want anyone using the underlying Google libraries directly.

To get this to work in Kodein, I do the following in `main`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  val kodein = Kodein {
    import(commonModule(args = args))
    import(googleModule)
    import(appModule)

    bind<App>() with singleton {
      App(
        api = instance(),
        argParser = instance()
      )
    }
  }

  kodein.direct.instance<App>().run()
}
```

then in `google`:

```
val googleModule = Kodein.Module("Google") {

  bind<CredentialRetriever>() with provider {
    CredentialRetriever(jsonFactory = instance(), transport = instance())
  }

  bind<Drive>() with provider {
    Drive.Builder(
      instance(),
      instance(),
      instance<CredentialRetriever>().retrieveCredentials()
    ).setApplicationName("Worker").build()
  }

  bind<GoogleApi>() with singleton {
    GoogleApi(drive = provider())
  }

  bind<JacksonFactory>() with provider {
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
  }

  bind<NetHttpTransport>() with provider{
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
  }
}
```

and finally in `common`:

```
fun commonModule(args: Array<String>) = Kodein.Module("Common") {
  bind<ArgParser>() with singleton { ArgParser(args = args) }
}
```

I tried implementing this in Dagger, and couldn't get it to work. My first attempt was to have a `Component` in `app` that relied on modules from `common` and `google`. This didn't work, because the generated code referenced classes that weren't exposed from `google` (like `Drive`). I could've fixed this by making them `api` dependencies, but I don't want to expose them:

```
// CredentialRetriever and GoogleApi were updated to have @Inject constructors

// GoogleApi also got an @Singleton

@Module
object GoogleModule {

  @Provides
  internal fun drive(
    transport: NetHttpTransport,
    jsonFactory: JacksonFactory,
    credentialRetriever: CredentialRetreiver
  ): Drive =
    Drive.Builder(
      transport,
      jsonFactory,
      credentialRetriever.retrieveCredentials()
    ).setApplicationName("Worker").build()

  @Provides
  internal fun jsonFactory(): JacksonFactory =
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

  @Provides
  internal fun netHttpTransport(): NetHttpTransport = 
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
}
```

Next I tried making a component per module (gradle module that is):

```
// in google module

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [GoogleModule::class])
interface GoogleComponent {
  fun googleApi(): GoogleApi
}

// in common module

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [CommonModule::class])
interface CommonComponent {
  fun argParser(): ArgParser
}
```

Then in `app` the fun started:

```
// results in "AppComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:"

@Component(dependencies = [CommonComponent::class, GoogleComponent::class])
interface AppComponent {
  fun app(): App
}
```

OK so let's make it scoped:

```
// results in "This @Singleton component cannot depend on scoped components:"

@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = [CommonComponent::class ,GoogleComponent::class])
interface AppComponent {
  fun app(): App
}
```

**EDIT**: tried making `AppComponent` use a custom scope:

```
// results in "AppComponent depends on more than one scoped component:"

@AppScope
@Component(dependencies = [CommonComponent::class ,GoogleComponent::class])
interface AppComponent {
  fun app(): App
}
```

How can I achieve this in Dagger? I've read the docs, I think I somewhat understand them, but I have no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of changing your example a bit to a) remove unnecessary details and b) simplify the setup.

Given 3 modules with the following classes:

```
// ----->> app <<-----
class App @Inject constructor(
        private val api: AbstractApi,
        private val argParser: ArgParser
)

// ----->> google <<-----
// expose a public interface
interface AbstractApi

// have our internal implementation
internal class GoogleApi @Inject constructor(
        private val argParser: ArgParser
) : AbstractApi

// ----->> common <<-----

// expose some common class
interface ArgParser
```

So we need to bind an implementation for `ArgParser` in both `google` as well as `app`. I used `ArgParser` as an example here how we could pass arguments to our API. `GoogleApi` is completely `internal` to make sure nothing leaks. We only expose the interface `AbstractApi`.

*I made `GoogleApi` internal to remove the Gradle complexity with implementation / api. The behavior is the same, maybe even a bit more strict: We have some class in our module that we can't expose. This way we have compiler validation as well.*

We can hide all our implementation details behind a component that we add to `google` to create our `GoogleApi` implementation for the interface.

```
// ----->> google
@Component(modules = [ApiModules::class])
interface ApiComponent {
    // has a provision method for our API
    fun api(): AbstractApi

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        // factory method to bind additional args that we need to supply
        fun create(@BindsInstance parser: ArgParser): ApiComponent
    }
}

@Module
internal interface ApiModules {
    @Binds
    fun bindApi(googleApi: GoogleApi): AbstractApi

}
```

We don't use a scope here, because the scope should be handled wherever this component gets used. `ArgParser` is an example for an argument that we may need to supply to create the object. We could use a `@Component.Builder` instead of the factory, too.

Dagger will generate the component within the same module (`google`), so there won't be any issues about referenced code. All we have to do is retrieve the API in our `app` module:

```
// ----->> app
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun app(): App
}

@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideParser(): ArgParser = object : ArgParser {} // just bind a dummy implementation

    @Provides
    fun provideApi(argParser: ArgParser): AbstractApi {
        return DaggerApiComponent.factory().create(argParser).api()
    }
}
```

We can now use the component factory to create an instance from our module. If we need a scope we can add it as usual on the `@Provides` method.

This setup should completely hide any detail from the `app` module behind the public interface. The generated code resides within the same module.

---

#### Why not expose a `@Module`? A `@Subcomponent`?

As reported, adding a module to a component will generate the factory code within that component as well, which will try to use non-referenced classes. The same would apply to a subcomponent.

#### Why not use a Component Dependency?

Since there is no scope on the component we might as well add it as a component dependency, but we wouldn't be able to add a scope then. Also we'd have a harder time passing in arguments, since we'd have to supply them when creating the component.

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to test this out in my project, but it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. If I understand correctly, the gist of it is that bindings from other modules are "marshalled" through to the `app` module through the `Component.Factory`?