# How to provide dependencies to main app module of "nested" modules

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a app with 3 different modules: `app(main)`,`api` and `repository`
My `app` module depends on `repository` module, that depends on `api` module:

`app -(depends)-> repository -(depends)-> api`

I would like to use Dagger2 in all 3 modules to inject dependencies in each other without exposing theses dependencies to the modules that doesn't need to see it.

Basically the `api` module will provide service related classes to communicate with the API

The `repository` module will use the `api` classes to coordinate the call of the resources

The `app` module will use only the `repository` classes directly, without knowing anything of the `api` module

Here are how my dagger modules/components are structured:

ApiModule:

```
    @Component(modules = [ApiModule::class])
    interface ApiComponent {

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {

            @BindsInstance
            fun requestApiModule(apiModule: ApiModule): Builder

            fun build(): ApiComponent
        }
    }

    @Module
    class ApiModule {

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideApiClient(apiConfig: ApiConfig) = ApiClient(apiConfig)

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideConsumerService(appConsumerService: AppConsumerService): ConsumerService = appConsumerService

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideParkingService(appParkingService: AppParkingService): ParkingService = appParkingService


    }
```

RepositoryModule:

```
    @Component(
        modules = [RepositoryModule::class],
        dependencies = [ApiComponent::class]
    )
    interface RepositoryComponent {

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {

            @BindsInstance
            fun requestRepositoryModule(repositoryModule: RepositoryModule): Builder

            fun apiComponent(apiComponent: ApiComponent): Builder

            fun build(): RepositoryComponent
        }
    }

    @Module
    class RepositoryModule {

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideLocalStorage(application: Application) = LocalStorage(application.applicationContext)

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideLocalSession(application: Application) = LocalSession(application.applicationContext)

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideApiConfig(apiRepositoryConfig: ApiRepositoryConfig): ApiConfig = apiRepositoryConfig

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideConsumerRepository(appConsumerRepository: AppConsumerRepository): ConsumerRepository =
            appConsumerRepository

        @Provides
        @Reusable
        fun provideParkingRepository(appParkingRepository: AppParkingRepository): ParkingRepository = appParkingRepository

    }
```

AppModule:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(
        modules = [ActivityModule::class, ViewModelModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class],
        dependencies = [RepositoryComponent::class]
    )
    interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<CustomApplication> {

        override fun inject(customApplication: CustomApplication)

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {

            @BindsInstance
            fun application(application: Application): Builder

            fun repositoryComponent(repositoryComponent: RepositoryComponent): Builder

            fun build(): ApplicationComponent

        }
    }
```

After trying to run the project I'm seeing the current errors in the build output

```
error: cannot access ApiComponent class file for com.spaces.api.module.ApiComponent not found  Consult the following stack trace for details
```

```
error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` files? I would like to see how you're establishing this: `app -(depends)-> repository -(depends)-> api`

Comment: There was also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56937717/1837367) a while back